# How do you protect controller actions with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise and a user can either be an admin or not (true, false).

Can someone help me figure out how to protect a controller action such as:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
```

I know Devise lets you call administrators by using in views but can this be used in controllers?:

```
if current_user.admin?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a good way to go?

In my controller add a before filter

    before_filter :if_admin, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]

and add a private method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add a filter, this way:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_access, :only => :new

  ...

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  protected
  def check_access
    redirect_to <whatever> and return unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

or use CanCan or something like that, to hold restrictions nicely

Comment: Thanks Alony, I was just thinking along the same lines. Why would one use "protected" and "private"

Comment: in case if the default route (match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))') is defined, protected/private clause would prevent user from accessing the filter as a normal action

Comment: in case of protected you will be able to use this filter in child controller, and in private case it can be accessed only from current controller

Comment: Your return is redundant as `check_access` is method and it is always return last operation result.

Comment: @alony that's not what protected vs private means in ruby. Check http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby

Comment: @grzuy, I know what it means in Ruby, thanks :) I was talking about the effect it has while applied to controllers

Comment: @alony Still, the same rule applies for rails controllers.

Comment: +1. Have read it more thoroughly, yes, you're right. So neither protected nor private will be visible for routing from both parent and child controllers. Thank you, @grzuy